# How to call a function by a variable name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question is sort of complex but I will try to word as best I can.

I am making a website with that involves a lot of javascript. I don't have everything setup so some of the scripts aren't hooked up with anything. I want to make a popup console that will allow me to   type in what function I want the computer to preform and have the computer do so.

1. Can I have a variable and then call a function with that variable example:

   ```
   var CodeApprentice = "Cat";
   function Cat(){
     document.write("kitten");
   } 
   function Dog(){
     document.write("puppy");
   }
   //Here is were I want to call the function with the variable   CodeApprentice   
   // and have it do the cat function
   function CodeApprentice();
   ```

I know I am not doing this correctly, but is there **a way to do this** or **am I just crazy**?

Comment: yes. in JS any function is an object. just assign `var CodeApprentice = Cat` and then `CodeApprentice();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any property of an object in two ways either dot notation

```
obj.propertyName
```

or using the property name as a key

```
obj["propertyName"]
```

any function you define in the global name sapce will become part of the global object so in your case you can do

```
//this is meant as a to the global object other names might be appropriate
//such as window depending on the context
this[CodeApprentice]()
```

to execute the funciton `Cat`

writing

```
function Cat() {
}
```

is equivalent to

```
Cat = function(){
}
```

where the latter is more explicitly showing that it's actually a property of `this`being set (I didn't say it's obvious just that it hides the fact less than the previous)

as a final note it's a general convention that functions that start with an upper case letter are constructors and should be called with the new key word e.g. `new Cat()` since that's probably not what you want in this case you should think about renaming the function (if the actual code has functions starting with upper case letters)

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for answering my question so well. Your answer was well put together and you really helped me understand how it works. :)

Answer (score 3):

you can store all the available functions in an object

```
var availableFunctions {
  cat: correspondingFunction
}
```

then you can get input as a string

```
var input = 'cat';

availableFunctions[input]();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.call` or `.apply`

```
var codeApprentice = Cat;

codeApprentice.call(null);
```

You could have a cleaner solution with some better composition

```
// my_class.js
var MyClass = function() {};

MyClass.Cat = function() {
  document.write("kitten");
};

MyClass.Dog = function() {
  document.write("puppy");
};

// usage
var codeApprentice = "Cat";
MyClass[codeApprentice].call(null);
// => "kitten"
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m7S4b/2) with some HTML controls

Comment: that's different from `Cat()` since it set the `this`pointer to the object passed as the first argument in this case `null`. If you just did `codeApprentice()` then it would be the same as `Cat()`

Comment: So that would do the cat function?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/m7S4b/2/) you can see

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this and even pass parameters in it

```
var strFun = "Cat";
var strParam = "";

//Create the function
var fn = window[strFun];

//Call the function
fn(strParam);
```

Or you can do it using the `eval()` function like this

```
var strFun = "Cat";
var strParam = "";

//Create the function call from function name and parameter.
var funcCall = strFun + "('" + strParam + "');";

//Call the function
var ret = eval(funcCall);
```